# XCode 5.1.1 storyboard Localizations not show item when I added language string item

Tags: objective-c, string, ios7

XCode 5.1.1 storyboard Localizations not show item when I added language string item.

I will set Localizations in the storyboard.

I'm use xCode5.1.1 . I set in info "Localizations" Properties.

I add a item name is Chinese (traditional).

[image]

Then I add a string (Localizable.strings(Chinese).strings) in Supporting Files.

[image]

But there are not show my string item in my storyboard.so I can't select the add string file.

[image]

Have any one know how to resolve this question?

I'm use Xcode 5.1.1.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just add the `Localizable.strings` file over there. It's a universal file that is then used to localize all other languages. And that's it.

[image]

That's how it looks.

You then have to localize it yourself via the menu:

[image]

And then, when I add the new language from the menu it looks like this:

[image]

And then, magically, I've got a new localization everywhere!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I think my major problem was happened on   'when I selected Localizations properties add new language items. the new language menu not show up'. I was set on xcode ->taget->info->add new items call Localizations. then the new language menu not show. Do you know why? thank you very much. ( I was use xcode 5.1.1)

Comment: @dickfala it didn't show up because you were not using the file "Localizable.strings" That is your major problem.

Comment: Are Localizable.strings manual in support files  Folder? Is build new file Localizable.strings in support files, then manual build new strings file Localizable.strings(French) ? I try to build , but there are not show tree structure in Localizable.strings.  thank you~ @@?

Comment: Just create a new file in Xcode menu, no need for "manual build new strings file Localizable.strings(French)". Just the "Localizable.strings" and that's it.

Comment: sorry. what time point will show "new language menu"? Because I add xcode menu( left menu) file about Localizable.strings file. There are not show any menu or I add other file "Localizable.strings(French)" in left menu. there are not show new language menu dialog. :(

Comment: @dickfala see updated answer. Only there shall you add new localizations and there you choose what files to localize.

Comment: I know my problem!! Because I selected "Targets", It have to select "Project" . So out panel are not same. When I selected to "Project->Info" panel. It is can set like your answer . Thank you very much . :)